# How to disable FIFO and restransmit protocols in JGROUPS?

Tags: java, jgroups

I'm a newbie to Jgroups, but based on my understanding of the documentation, one of its key advantages is that one can disable the protocol elements one does not need/want (to achieve better performance). However, when I tried to disable anything that had to do with "FIFO" order of delivery and "guaranteeing delievery", I got the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Exception: events [GET_DIGEST SET_DIGEST ] are required by GMS, but not provided by any of the protocols below it
    at org.jgroups.stack.Configurator.sanityCheck(Configurator.java:320)
    at org.jgroups.stack.Configurator.connectProtocols(Configurator.java:197)
    at org.jgroups.stack.Configurator.setupProtocolStack(Configurator.java:115)
    at org.jgroups.stack.Configurator.setupProtocolStack(Configurator.java:49)
    at org.jgroups.stack.ProtocolStack.setup(ProtocolStack.java:475)
    at org.jgroups.JChannel.init(JChannel.java:965)
    at org.jgroups.JChannel.<init>(JChannel.java:148)
    at org.jgroups.JChannel.<init>(JChannel.java:130)
    at RpcDispatcherTest.start(RpcDispatcherTest.java:29)
    at RpcDispatcherTest.main(RpcDispatcherTest.java:83)
```

My xml config file looks like this:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns="urn:org:jgroups"
        xsi:schemaLocation="urn:org:jgroups http://www.jgroups.org/schema/jgroups.xsd">
    <TCP bind_addr="127.0.0.1"
            bind_port="7800"
         recv_buf_size="${tcp.recv_buf_size:130k}"
         send_buf_size="${tcp.send_buf_size:130k}"
         max_bundle_size="64K"
         sock_conn_timeout="300"
         enable_diagnostics="true"
         thread_pool.min_threads="10"
         thread_pool.max_threads="20"
         thread_pool.keep_alive_time="30000"
         stats = "false"
    />
    <TCPPING initial_hosts="127.0.0.1[7800]"
             port_range="0" stats = "false"/>
    <MERGE3  min_interval="10000"
             max_interval="30000" stats = "false"/>
    <FD_SOCK stats = "false"/>
    <FD timeout="3000" max_tries="3" stats = "false" />
    <VERIFY_SUSPECT timeout="1500" stats = "false" />

    <pbcast.GMS print_local_addr="true" join_timeout="2000"
                view_bundling="true" stats = "false"/>
</config>
```

If I comment out the last protocol (the pgcast.GMS one), I do NOT get errors and it "seems" to work on a single windows VM (on Google Cloud), but if I start up a 2nd jvm (still on the same Windows machine), then I notice that each jvm is in a "separate" cluster and doesn't see the other. (In the "normal tcp.xml" config (which includes the NACKA and XXXX protocols), eg

```
<pbcast.NAKACK2 use_mcast_xmit="false"
                   discard_delivered_msgs="true"
                    stats = "false"/>
    <UNICAST3 stats = "false"/>
    <!--<pbcast.STABLE desired_avg_gossip="50000"-->
                   <!--max_bytes="4M"/>-->
```

everything works "as expected", ie if I start a 2nd JVM on the same windows machine, the 2nd JVM does appear to join the 1st JVM's cluster and so messages sent on the 2nd JVM appear in the 1st JVM and vice-versa.

So, is there a way to disable UNICAST3 and NAKACK2 (essentially, anything that has to do with FIFO ordering or guaranteeing message delivery) but still include the logic needed to ensure a "working complete cluster" that also captures which nodes leave/join the cluster (eg pbcast.GMS logic?) I couldn't figure out how....

(Background info: I'm trying to improve performance, and I suspect the somewhat slow performance is because of the "guaranteed message delivery" and "FIFO" protocols, which I do not think I need because a) I'm using TCP and b) the messages can be sent in any order. (That said, I'm assuming that TCP, almost by definition, does the guaranteeing of message delivery, since that's critical.) I'm also on Google Cloud, where I think the "guaranteeing" aspect of TCP logic runs on highly optimized routers and Multicast is not allowed anyways, which supresses one of the main advantages of UDP multicast.)

Finally (and I do *NOT* think this is needed), but here's my test code (which is just a slight modification of the demo that comes with JGroups 4.0):

```
import org.jgroups.Address;
import org.jgroups.JChannel;
import org.jgroups.Message;
import org.jgroups.blocks.*;
import org.jgroups.util.RspList;
import org.jgroups.util.Util;

import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class RpcDispatcherTest {
    JChannel channel;
    RpcDispatcher disp;
    RspList rsp_list;
    String             props = "gs-tcp.xml"; // set by application

    public static int print(int number) throws Exception {
        return number;
    }

    public void start() throws Exception {

        RequestOptions opts=new RequestOptions(ResponseMode.GET_FIRST, 1000);
        channel=new JChannel(props);
        disp=new RpcDispatcher(channel, this);
        channel.connect("RpcDispatcherTestGroup");

        final Address myCurAddress = channel.getAddress();
        System.out.println("Currrent address is " + myCurAddress + " all members address are " + channel.getView().getMembers().toString());


        final long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        final IntStream x = IntStream.range(0, 1_000_000);
        final AtomicInteger cnt = new AtomicInteger();
        x.asLongStream().parallel().forEach(l -> {
            try {
            final int i = (int) l;
                if (i % (100) == 0) {
                    System.out.println("At " + i + " on thread  + " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
                }


            final MethodCall call=new MethodCall(getClass().getMethod("print", int.class));
            call.setArgs(i);
            final CompletableFuture<Integer> response = disp.<Integer>callRemoteMethodWithFuture(myCurAddress, call, opts);
            response.thenAccept(integer -> {
                    if (integer % (1024*8) == 0) {
                        System.out.println("At " + cnt.incrementAndGet() + " Execution time for " + integer + " is " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - t1)/1000f);
                    }
                });
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

     //   Util.close(disp, channel);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new RpcDispatcherTest().start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a way to disable all reliable message transmission protocols because at least the `GMS` protocol depends on `NAKACK2`. `GMS` requires that a protocol above provides the `GET_DIGEST` event, which is provided by `NAKACK2`.

But removing the `UNICAST3` protocol did help a lot and the performance is much better now.